# Dynamic urls in flask throw an 404

Tags: flask, routes, http-status-code-404

I want to build a small webshop as a CS50 project and have trouble routing from the product page to the order page. It is the first time I work with dynamic paths so it might be something wrong with my logic there but I can`t figure it out on my own...

The python code is pretty simple

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

products = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Motiv 1", "price": 9.99, "src": "motiv_1.png"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Motiv 2", "price": 29.99, "src": "motiv_2.jpeg"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Motiv 3", "price": 39.99, "src": "motiv_3.jpeg"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Motiv 4", "price": 49.99, "src": "motiv_4.jpeg"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Motiv 5", "price": 59.99, "src": "motiv_5.png"},
    {"id": 6, "name": "Motiv 6", "price": 69.99, "src": "motiv_6.jpeg"},
]


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", products=products)


@app.route("/product/<int:product_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def product(product_id):
    product = None
    for p in products:
        if p["id"] == product_id:
            product = p

    if request.method == "POST":
        return redirect(url_for("order", product=product))
    else:
        return render_template("product.html", product=product)
        
@app.route("/order", methods=["GET","POST"])
def order():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("order.html", product=product)
    
    else:
        return

   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
html index

{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block header %}
{% block title %}Übersicht{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
            <div class="main_container">
                <h1>something something</h1>
        <div class="grid_container">
            {% for product in products %}
            <a href="/product/{{ product.id }}"><img id="{{ product.id }}" name="{{ product.name }}" src="static/imgs/{{ product.src }}" alt="{{ product.name }}"><br>{{ product.name }}</a>
            
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    
{% endblock %}


product page

{% extends 'layout.html' %}
    {% block header %}
    <h1>{% block title %}{{ product.name }}{% endblock %} </h1>
    {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}
        <div class="product_container">
            <img src="../static/imgs/{{ product.src }}" alt="Motiv">
            <p>Preis: {{ product.price }} €</p>
            <form action="order" method="post"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="{{ product.name }}" value="{{ product.id }}">Kaufe {{ product.name }}</button>
            </form>
            <p><a href="/">Zum Shop</a></p>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The app works fine for rendering all products in a grid on index and rendering the individual product pages (product/1 - product/6). When I click on the buy button on /product/1 it throws an 404 error and can`t find product/order. Why is that so? Can it be found in the templates folder if the path is product/order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the form you used a relative URL: `action="order"`, so the action target becomes `/product/order` instead of `/order`. You should use the [`url_for()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.url_for) function in the templates as well:

```
action="{{ url_for('order') }}"
```